# Distance not getting when given the "near" parameter

Tags: android, google-maps, foursquare, gmsplacepicker

I am referring to [this sample app](https://github.com/foursquare/placepicker-sdk-sample). I have included placepicker-sdk into my project when I am searching particular location it's showing with the distance but when I am providing `near` parameter then it's not showing the distance.

I want to show distance as well when I am providing the `near` parameter.

Let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: You should provide some code or what you are testing without that there is little chance than anyone would help you.

Comment: You will have to build that yourself. Please provide some code of what you've tried. The placepicker SDK calculates distance from the search lat/lng to the venue lat/lng. When you use a `near` param there's no reference point to start the distance calculation from.